# Construct logic statements through parsing a file

Tags: c++, algorithm, fileparsing

I have been presented the problem of reading an input file that contains logic statements, and am required to construct a Truth Table to determine whether an ASK matches any/all models that are determined. An example of some data I may expect to read in is:

`(p & z => x)` => `((p | d) & z)`

Please don't get too caught up in the example and whether it really makes sense, I just made it up to show the different compositions I may be presented with. Multiple such statements can be separated with semicolons.

I have sorted out the semicolon splitting without any dramas, and now have a vector of strings containing each separate statement, where each string is as presented above. Now without parenthesis being involved, I believe determining the statements would be rather straight forward, but with their involvement I am now required to compute different sections before others. EG:

`(p | d) = result`     and then    `(result & x)`

I have seen people discussing the concept of using a stack to determine if open brackets are closed properly, but I do not believe that this would be appropriate for my situation as this would not allow me to determine what statements were inside what set of parenthesis.

The current idea I have is to use the stack idea, and try to determine the "depth" of a statement (essentially how far it is nested) and then mark this number with each statement, but I believe this sounds like an inelegant solution. Does anyone have any tips as to how I should construct an algorithm to properly address the problem?

Comment: Can't you use the [shunting yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) for this? It should take care of parenheses and the different precedence of the logical operators.

Comment: @MOehm I will check it out right now, thanks for the link. I'll leave a comment here shortly.

Comment: You could construct a binary tree

Comment: Also you can implement [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)

Comment: So far the Shunting Yard algorithm seem like the way to go. The recursive descent parser looked interesting, but probably more complex than I would require. The binary tree was also a really good way of representing the data I found. I shall try implementing the Shunting Yard algorithm first and see what progress I can make. Thanks all for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a tree of the expressions, where your variables are leaves.

Your expression will then become:

```
        =>
       / \
      /   \
     /     \
    =>      &
   / \     / \
  &   X   |   Z
 / \     / \
p   z   P   D
```

Once you have built this kind of representation, the evaluation is straightforward.

Another approach, with the same result, is reducing your expression to something like RPN (where you can use your stack idea):

```
P, Z, &, X, =>, P, D, |, Z, &, =>
```

As suggested in the comments, you can do it with the shunting yard algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for this, it has taken me quite a few hours to process this particular problem, but this has been extremely helpful. I did end up going with the RPN method, which seems to have done the trick quite nicely. One of the things that I think should be noted is that there is no order of operations in regards to the logic operators, so it is essentially first come, first served (unless there are parenthesis involved).